# Latest XP Drivers for Intel Integrated Graphics

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics

On the Intel site I'm struggling to find what the latest driver version is for certain chipsets. From a system info tool I have several PCs (laptops) with the following reported graphics:

- Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
- Intel(R) Q35 Express Chipset Family
- Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset

All use the same driver igxprd32.dll at version 6.14.0010.4xxx (last 3 digits vary). All PCs are XP 32 bit.

I am not certain but I think these are all using the same basic chipset. More than likely the drivers were never updated so I wondered what version might be relevant.

Any help on tracking down the latest driver version (I just need the number, so I can see how out of date they are) and figuring out which chips these [cards are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#Specifications) would be great.

Is it possible to get a history of when different versions were released so I can see *how* old the current drivers are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are laptops you can't be guaranteed the drivers from intel won't cause problems. It's always best to use the OEM (e.g. Dell, Lenove, HP) driver website/utility

Comment: I've read this at multiple hardware vendor sites and would agree with their "supported configurations" stance.  In production, however, we've consolidated our drivers for more than 15 models, 5 vendors, using the hardware manufacturer's drivers instead of OEM, without issue.  In particular, for wifi cards, this came at the suggestion of the AP vendor and site survey consultants.